# Is there a way to get a TornadoFX tabpane to show at bottom of screen?

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

Is there a way to get a TornadoFX tabpane to show at bottom of screen?

```
class ChartScreen : View("Chart") {

    override val root = form {
        tabpane {
            tab("Report") {
                hbox {
                    this += Button("Hello 1")
                }
            }
            tab("Data Entry") {
                hbox {
                    this += Button("Hello 2")
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear if you want the tabs to be at the bottom of the screen or the tabs themselves to be at the bottom of the tab pane.

If you want the tabs to be at the bottom, you can configure the `side` property of the `TabPane`. If you want the tabpane to be at the bottom of the screen, pleace it in the bottom area of a `BorderPane`. Wrapping the `TabPane` in a `Form` like you did is probably not the best way to express your layout.

The following example incorporates both of these solutions.

Please also note the usages of the button builders in this example.

```
class ChartScreen : View("Chart") {

    override val root = borderpane {
        bottom {
            tabpane {
                side = Side.BOTTOM

                tab("Report") {
                    hbox {
                        button("Hello 1")
                    }
                }
                tab("Data Entry") {
                    hbox {
                        button("Hello 2")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```